# Access 'Join not supported' Moving LEFT Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join

I've done some research here and I understand that in Access nested joins cause issues.

I believe that is the issue in the first example.

```
SELECT 
Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassDescription,
Recipes.RecipeTitle,
Recipes.Preparation,
Ingredients.IngredientName,
Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeSeqNo,
Recipe_Ingredients.Amount,
Measurements.MeasurementDescription
FROM (((
Recipe_Classes
LEFT JOIN Recipes
ON Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassID = Recipes.RecipeClassID)
INNER JOIN Recipe_Ingredients
ON Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID)
INNER JOIN Ingredients
ON Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID)
INNER JOIN Measurements
ON Measurements.MeasureAmountID = Recipe_Ingredients.MeasureAmountID
ORDER BY RecipeTitle, RecipeSeqNo;
```

I made an attempt to remove the nesting and created a right join in this example

```
 SELECT 
    Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassDescription,
    Recipes.RecipeTitle,
    Recipes.Preparation,
    Ingredients.IngredientName,
    Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeSeqNo,
    Recipe_Ingredients.Amount,
    Measurements.MeasurementDescription
    FROM (((
    Ingredients
    INNER JOIN Recipe_Ingredients
    ON Ingredeints.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID)
    INNER JOIN Measurements
    ON Measurements.MeasureAmountID = Recipe_Ingredients.MeasureAmountID)
    INNER JOIN Recipes
    ON Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID)
    RIGHT JOIN Recipe_Classes
    ON Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassID = Recipes.RecipeClassID
    ORDER BY RecipeTitle, RecipeSeqNo;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be the `left join` that is not needed.  Try this `from` clause:

```
SELECT Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassDescription,
       Recipes.RecipeTitle,
       Recipes.Preparation,
       Ingredients.IngredientName,
       Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeSeqNo,
       Recipe_Ingredients.Amount,
       Measurements.MeasurementDescription
FROM (((Recipes LEFT JOIN
        Recipe_Classes
        ON Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassID = Recipes.RecipeClassID
       ) LEFT JOIN
       Recipe_Ingredients
       ON Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
      ) LEFT JOIN
      Ingredients
      ON Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID
     ) LEFT JOIN Measurements
     ON Measurements.MeasureAmountID = Recipe_Ingredients.MeasureAmountID
ORDER BY RecipeTitle, RecipeSeqNo;
```

Once you start with `LEFT JOIN`s, generally all the remaining joins should also be `LEFT JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0):

Since your main focal point table is *Recipe_Ingredients*, consider starting with this table in `FROM` and then `JOIN` the other parent tables and even nest the *Recipes* and *Recipe_Classes* pair:

```
SELECT 
    c.RecipeClassDescription,
    r.RecipeTitle,
    r.Preparation,
    i.IngredientName,
    ri.RecipeSeqNo,
    ri.Amount,
    m.MeasurementDescription
FROM 
  ((Recipe_Ingredients ri    
    INNER JOIN (Recipes r 
                RIGHT JOIN Recipe_Classes c
                      ON c.RecipeClassID = r.RecipeClassID)
          ON r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID)
    INNER JOIN Ingredients i
          ON i.IngredientID = ri.IngredientID)
    INNER JOIN Measurements m
          ON m.MeasureAmountID = ri.MeasureAmountID

ORDER BY r.RecipeTitle, ri.RecipeSeqNo;
```

Of course this is untested without data. Due to Access' `JOIN` requirements like parnetheses, it is often recommended for new users to build complex queries with MS Access' GUI Query Design then modify generated SQL as needed.